# creating new column based on multiple values of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has these values in one of its columns:

In:

```
df.line.unique()
```

Out:

```
array(['Line71A', 'Line71B', 'Line75B', 'Line79A', 'Line79B', 'Line75A', 'Line74A', 'Line74B',
       'Line70A', 'Line70B', 'Line58B', 'Line70', 'Line71', 'Line74', 'Line75', 'Line79', 'Line58'],
      dtype=object)
```

And I would like to create a new column with 2 values based on if the value string contains LineXX, like so:

```
if (df.line.str.contains("Line70")  or (df.line.str.contains("Line71") or (df.line.str.contains("Line79")):
   return 1
else:
   return 0
```

So the value should be 1 in the new column, `box_type`, if the values in `df.line` contains "Line70", "Line71", "Line79" and the rest should be 0

I tried doing this with this code:

```
df['box_type'] = df.line.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.contains('Line70') or x.contains('Line71') or x.contains('Line79') else 0)
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

And I tried adding `.str` in between `x` and `contains`, like `x.str.contains()`, but that also gave an error.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
df['box_type'] = df.line.str.contains('70|71|79')
```

Sample data:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'line':np.random.choice(a, 10)})
```

Output:

```
      line  box_type
0  Line75A     False
1   Line70      True
2   Line71      True
3  Line70A      True
4  Line70B      True
5   Line70      True
6  Line75A     False
7   Line79      True
8  Line71A      True
9   Line58     False
```

Comment: Great answer! I would make only two recommendations. In order to fulfill the desired output from the original question, I would add `.astype(int) to cast the `bool` values to 1 and 0, and (of much less importance) when selecting columns, it's better to recommend `df['line']` over `df.line`

Comment: Thanks @G.Anderson, two valid points. Although, I tend to use `.` access for those that are not internal methods/properties just to save some (hard-to-reach) characters.

Comment: I definitely understand the instinct. I've had to break myself of that habit after I accidentally caused myself a full day's extra work by messing up a `df['name']` column with the `df.name` attribute -_-